# How can I find out the time-complexity of a method-call when the access to the source is hard/not possible?

Tags: algorithm

Since OOP is quite neat to abstract away the implementation I still find myself asking what kind of time-complexity a certain operation has when using it.

**Example:** Documentation of Collection.min

```
/**
 * Returns the minimum element of the given collection, according to the
 * <i>natural ordering</i> of its elements.  All elements in the
 * collection must implement the <tt>Comparable</tt> interface.
 * Furthermore, all elements in the collection must be <i>mutually
 * comparable</i> (that is, <tt>e1.compareTo(e2)</tt> must not throw a
 * <tt>ClassCastException</tt> for any elements <tt>e1</tt> and
 * <tt>e2</tt> in the collection).<p>
 *
 * This method iterates over the entire collection, hence it requires
 * time proportional to the size of the collection.
 *
 * @param  <T> the class of the objects in the collection
 * @param  coll the collection whose minimum element is to be determined.
 * @return the minimum element of the given collection, according
 *         to the <i>natural ordering</i> of its elements.
 * @throws ClassCastException if the collection contains elements that are
 *         not <i>mutually comparable</i> (for example, strings and
 *         integers).
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if the collection is empty.
 * @see Comparable
 */
```

This is a trivial example since it's easy to see when looking at the source but it gets harder when the implementation is more complicated or not visible at all.

**My Question:** How can I quickly determine the time-complexity in order to decide if it's viable to use ? Try and Error ? Time-logging ?

**EDIT:** It is not the best example since it's also written in the documentation but the question still remains: What if it's not written in docu ?

Comment: You could read the documentation - it's in the snippet you posted.

Comment: The question still remains, what if I can't find it in the docu ? Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obviously not feasible to determine the time-complexity of a black-box function. Complexity is a worst-case definition. You can have a function which runs in linear time for most input but blows up and takes millions of years for 1 out of 100 billion inputs. There is no way to rule this out.

On the other hand, if you have a reasonable probability distribution on possible inputs of a given size, you can use statistical methods to estimate the average time complexity for the various size, and then use curve-fitting to come up with a heuristic curve to estimate average run time.

A realistic example. The [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) for linear programming runs very quickly in practice. But it was proven in the 1970s (via very carefully constructed examples) to have exponential time complexity. Nevertheless, the simplex algorithm is still heavily used due to its nice average time complexity. Since then polynomial time algorithms for linear programming have been discovered and have been implemented. If you have a method which solves linear programming problems then there might be no easy way of knowing if it implements the exponential time simplex algorithm or one of the more recent polynomial time algorithms.

(Note that it might be possible to decompile a function -- but in that case it is no longer black-box.)